# conemu Log console output option not working

Tags: logging, conemu

I have just installed the 64bit version of ConEmu-Maximus5 (ConEmuSetup.160609.exe) on Windows 10 64bit.  I went to Settings/Features and ticked: 'Log console output (*)', which has the default value of:  %ConEmuDir%\Logs\

I went to Settings/Startup/Environment and confirmed that the option to Add %ConEmuDir% ot %PATH% was ticked, and the textbox had the correct default value of:  set PATH=%ConEmuBaseDir%\Scripts;%PATH%

I then saved the settings and shut down the ConEmu console.  I then started a new ConEmu console and ran a program that printed a heap of lines out to the console.

I then went to C:\Program Files\ConEmu, but there was no Log directory there.
I then created one and ran the console program again, but no log file was created.

What am I doing wrong here... how come the output is not being logged as the documentation says it should be?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I did two things to get this to work.
In Windows 10 I check the:

```
Control Panel/System/Advanced System Settings/Environment Variables/
```

and could not see the ConEmu in the path, or the %ConEmuDir% variable, so I added these.
Then when I restarted the console it showed the log file URL but said Access Denied in the console on startup.  I then restarted it in Admin mode and the log file was created.

Hopefully this saves someone else some time ;)